# Have more descriptive actions in review histories

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, review-suspension

Alright, so yeah. I did something dumb. I got myself banned from reviewing on SO somehow. I'm not here to complain...

## ***I Have been banned, and I embrace it!***

[image: Banned Picture]

Alright. I screwed up somewhere. More than once. When I think about it, I don't think the ban is a big deal. However, I've been eager to see exactly where I've screwed up.

First, the link that you all see is the one I screwed up that got me banned. But where are the other "incorrect' reviews? I can go to my history, the "First Posts", but here is all I see: <kbd>No Action Needed</kbd> and <kbd>Reviewed</kbd>. I can't really tell what I've screwed up. I can't even tell the meaning of "Reviewed".

Even in Triage, it's not that descriptive. There are the actions that I've taken, but I can't tell where I've screwed up. From the actions that I can click on, my reviews seem to be on par with the rest of the community. I don't recall having reviewed many audits, but if I've screwed up, I would like to know where.

So for the request...

For users who are in a review ban, or simply just all users, can we have them know which reviews they have made were audits, and whether they successfully passed them or not on the review history page? I feel that many people who pass or fail audits see what went wrong for the short-term, but are never actually able to remember or improve upon what they have done. As I can tell what are audits (just by randomly selecting a review here and there, and then figuring out what the result was), this would be very helpful to the community.